# How to get websocket in webclient of gargoylesoftware

Tags: java, htmlunit, web-client

Is Websocket supported in gargoylesoftware library?  I want to get websocket object in webclient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `WebSocket` is supported since version 2.11.  However, it is always recommended to use the latest version.

Please ensure you use [BrowserVersion](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/BrowserVersion.html) with recent browser, e.g. `CHROME`, `FIREFOX_38`, or `INTERNET_EXPLORER_11`.

E.g.:

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
```

HtmlUnit will automatically handle the JavaScript with `WebSocket`.

**Update:**

To intercept the requests and responses, you can use:

```
    new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {

        public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
            WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
            if (request.getUrl().toExternalForm().contains("my_url")) {
                String content = response.getContentAsString("UTF-8");

                //change content

                WebResponseData data = new WebResponseData(content.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                        response.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusMessage(), response.getResponseHeaders());
                response = new WebResponse(data, request, response.getLoadTime());
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Then how can i get the websocket object in java? I want to get all response from websocket in java. Can? Or how to intercept all request and response of http?

Comment: The request is not fired by me. It is auto executed inside the html page's javascript. So how to intercept all request?

Comment: Would you test it please? This code doesn't trigger anything, still it intercepts all requests, whether user-generated or JavaScript-generated

Comment: It just print the some request but then the program end. actually it is gwt app. it will stream data in background. how to let the javascript continue run there?

Comment: i am able to capture ajax response now. but websocket still not working :(

Comment: Finally i did it. So how can i buy u starbuc? pls gv me your starbuc card id

Comment: @robottech can you explain how you succeeded ? I also need to capture websocket data.

Comment: `code`webClient.setWebConnection(new InterceptWebConnection(webClient));
  webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
  
  
  class InterceptWebConnection extends FalsifyingWebConnection {
  public InterceptWebConnection(WebClient webClient) throws IllegalArgumentException {
   super(webClient);
  }

  @Override
  public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {  @Derlin